# Laravel 5.2 eloquent save() method store number 0 in Oracle become 4294967296

Tags: php, oracle, laravel, laravel-5

I'm having a problem when saving data with eloquent save() method.

For example when I insert a number like 0, the number in the table become 4294967296.

[oracle table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I13iC.jpg)

Here is my code:

```
$user = new User;
$user->username = 'lolol';
$user->name = 'lolol';
$user->email = 'lolol@lolol.com';
$user->domain = 'lolol';
$user->active_directory = 0;
$user->save();
```

But, there is no problem when I'm using raw query like this:

```
DB::insert('insert into users (id, username, name, email, active_directory, domain) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)', [10,'dayle', 'Dayle', 'dayle', '0', 'esdm']);
```

it will insert 0 into table.

Is there any way to solve this problem?

Thank you for your help and answer.

Comment: can you post your table design ?

Comment: in your query you insert a string with elqouent it`s 0

Comment: Here's my table design from migration:
`$table->increments('id');
$table->string('username', 30)->unique();
$table->string('name', 100);
$table->string('email')->unique();
$table->string('password');
$table->integer('active_directory');
$table->rememberToken();
$table->timestamps();`

Comment: When I use save() method to store number 0 in table, it become 4294967296. But, when I use raw query, it will store 0, not 4294967296. How to solve this? Because I want to use the save() method instead of raw query in laravel.

Comment: 4294967296 is not a random number. It's the largest value which will fit into a 32bit integer. So it seems possible you might be running into some overflow bug.

Comment: But the thing is when I using raw query, it works and store the exact number. Not like 4294967296. Another example is when I try to store another number like 14, it become 4294967310.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may indeed be a bug here, but considering passing the query a string instead of a integer works, a simple workaround would be to implement a setter mutator inside your User model which casts your active_directory attribute to string before saving it.

```
//other User model methods....
public function setActiveDirectoryAttribute($attrValue){
    $this->attributes['active_directory'] = (string) $attrValue;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work. It show error message: `ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL`. 
I try to casting with: 
`protected $casts = [
        'id' => 'integer',
        'active_directory' => 'integer',
    ];` still not working too.

Comment: Apologies, you have to set the attribute with $this->attributes['active_directory'] = 'value' in order for the cast to work. Edited my comment. Also $casts won't work as this is only used when fetching the data from the DB to the model, not when setting it.

Comment: Cool. It works. You really saved my day. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer. Btw, I have a feeling your dbschema is wrong somehow. Can you check your db structure (in the db itself, not in the migration) and tell us what types exactly are your columns? Thanks!

Comment: Of course. Here's my db structure: `"ID" NUMBER(10,0), 
"USERNAME" VARCHAR2(30 BYTE), 
"NAME" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE), 
"EMAIL" VARCHAR2(255 BYTE), 
"password" VARCHAR2(255 BYTE), 
"ACTIVE_DIRECTORY" NUMBER(10,0), 
"STATUS" VARCHAR2(10 BYTE) DEFAULT 'ACTV', 
"REMEMBER_TOKEN" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE), 
"CREATED_AT" TIMESTAMP (6), 
"UPDATED_AT" TIMESTAMP (6), 
"DOMAIN" VARCHAR2(50 BYTE)`. 
The strange thing is, when I try to cast to integer in mutator it doesn't work. Instead, it will work if I casting it to string.